# Is there a way to construct the full url before calling the get method?

Tags: python-3.x, api

I'm trying to implement a cache file so I don't need to call the API every time if, for example, I already called it today and I have the info in my cache file.

When I have some parameters, I need to get the full url as string to check if that url was called before and it's in the cache file, before actually calling again the the API. I have been doing some research and reading the python3 requests library, but haven't found anything.

Below there is an example, but trying to avoid the get method.

```
import requests

d = {"term": "Ann Arbor", "entity": "podcast"}
response = requests.get("https://itunes.apple.com/search", params = d)
```

I know that `response.url` will give me the full url `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Ann+Arbor&entity=podcast` but I was wondering if there is another way to do this?

Thanks for any help/idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap `requests.get` in another function then you don't have to construct the URL.

For example, using `functools.lru_cache` and a wrapper function:

```
import requests
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def search_itunes(**params):
    print('Making requests with params:', params)
    return requests.get("https://itunes.apple.com/search", params=params)


print(search_itunes(**{"term": "Ann Arbor", "entity": "podcast"}))
print(search_itunes(**{"term": "Ann Arbor", "entity": "podcast"}))
```

Running this code outputs

```
Making requests with params: {'term': 'Ann Arbor', 'entity': 'podcast'}
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
```

You can see that only one request was made as the `search_itunes` was called only once. The second "response" was cached. Of course if we change the params then the function will be called again (and a new request will be made):

```
print(search_itunes(**{"term": "Ann Arbor", "entity": "podcast"}))
print(search_itunes(**{"term": "Ann Arbor", "entity": "podcast"}))
print(search_itunes(**{"term": "Not Ann Arbor", "entity": "podcast"}))
```

This outputs

```
Making requests with params: {'term': 'Ann Arbor', 'entity': 'podcast'}
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
Making requests with params: {'term': 'Not Ann Arbor', 'entity': 'podcast'}
<Response [200]>
```

---

If you insist on manually constructing the URL there are several methods of doing so.

You can do it manually:

```
params = {"term": "Ann Arbor", "entity": "podcast"}
print("https://itunes.apple.com/search?{}".format("&".join("{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in params.items())))
```

outputs

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Ann Arbor&entity=podcast
```

But it will be better to use an actual URL-handling library such as [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) (the only caveat is that you'll need to use a tuple):

```
from urllib.parse import urlunparse

print(urlunparse(('https', 'itunes.apple.com', '/search', '', 'term=Ann Arbor&entity=podcast', '')))
```

outputs

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Ann Arbor&entity=podcast
```